# Длина штриха в border-style: dashed. Возможно ли регулировать?

Tags: html, css, svg

Нужно сделать блок с такой обводкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если использовать `border: 2px dashed #15acd3`, то получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли через CSS задавать как длину штриха и отступы между штриками?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`background-image` с SVG. Регулировать расстояния между черточкам нужно в свойстве `stroke-dasharray`.

> Источник: [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: 5 20'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

К сожалению, этого нельзя сделать. Но, если вам хочется кастомный бордер, то можно использовать вариант с картинкой:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-image: url('borderImageURL') 2 fill repeat;
```

Не забудьте про вендорные префиксы для свойства border-imagе, если нужна повышенная кросбраузерность.

Answer (score 3):

в html:

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```

в css:

```
.hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 40%, red 40%);
    background-size: 10px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```